# Low level mouse hook and DirectX

Tags: .net, directx, mouse, hook, directinput

I'm building an application which needs to filter some mouse clicks system-wide. That is, I need to make the system ignore some mouse button clicks at special occasions.

I use low level mouse hook and `SetWindowsHookEx` to filter out these clicks. It works relatively well, except for `WPF` applications. I guess that's because these applications use `DirectX` and `DirectInput` for input processing, and that's why I can't filter out clicks in these applications, since they get the input directly from the driver.

Is there any way how to filter clicks in `WPF`/`DirectX` applications?

I know it is generally not good idea to globally filter clicks, but it is crucial for my application, and I will make sure that it is not filtered in games and other programs. But `WPF` applications have ordinary `GUI`, so I need to filter clicks in them as well.

### Update

I guess I could solve this problem by writing my own filtering driver, but since I don't have any experience in writing drivers, please let me know if there is any other solution.

### API Hooking Resources

I've found some helpful links regarding API hooking. Use this as a reference.

[Hooking Windows API](http://web.archive.org/web/20040426083909/29a.host.sk/29a-7/Articles/29A-7.019)
[API hooking revealed](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx)
[API hooking revealed Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/APIHookingPart2.aspx)
[Hijack Textout Calls From Notepad](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/W-P/dll/hooking/article.php/c3639)
[madCodeHook](http://help.madshi.net/madCodeHook.htm)
[IAT Function Hooking](http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/IAT_Hooking.html)

## FINAL SOLUTION

[WPF does not use DirectInput, but standard Win32 messages for input handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036143/what-does-wpf-use-to-capture-mouse-and-keyboard-input) (except for stylus, which is the source for all problems for me, because I use stylus for development, and I wasn't aware WPF apps are stylus-aware). However for filtering clicks in apps that use DirectInput, one would have to hook API, as the accepted answer explains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a method called API hooking - you override specific calls to library functions and give them your own behavior. There are many hooking libraries out there that simplify this task, the most used ones are: 
* [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/)
* [MadCodeHook](http://madshi.net/)
* [Deviare API Hook](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/)
* [API Hijack](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/apihijack.aspx)

Also see [Wikipedia example of hooking Direct3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking#Hooking_Direct3D).

You just need to insert your hooking library into each process in the system but judging from your question I assume you've already achieved that.

Comment: I actually use `WH_MOUSE_LL`, which does not need it's own `.dll`. Nevertheless, this is actually a very good idea! But I will need to learn `DirectX` and `DirectInput`, to hook the right functions. :-(

Comment: And I don't know if `WPF` actually uses `DirectInput` or `XInput`, so I will probably need to hook both.

Comment: Yes, you will have to find out which functions to hook in DirectInput and XInput but that shouldn't take much time I guess, Google is on your side. I have never used DirectInput/XInput directly so can't be of any help here.